# Why /bin/init -> ../lib/systemd/systemd instead of /bin/init -> /lib/systemd/systemd in Arch linux?

Tags: ubuntu, arch-linux, systemd

I am learning Linux. For testing whether kernel will invoke init through boot process, I did:

```
sudo rm /sbin/init
```

and rebooted. As I expected, `Ubuntu` was not able to boot successfully since /sbin/init didn't exist. Then, to fix it, I used a bootable usb to mount, chroot...finally re-symbol-linked it:

```
ln -s /lib/systemd/systemd /sbin/init
```

rebooted...My `Ubuntu` boot successfully again.

But, It doesn't work in `Arch` by the same way above. How to explain this ?
(Arch and Ubuntu both use `systemd` as init, and I install them in only one partition separately.)

(After removing /sbin/init in Arch, it showed ERROR: `Root device mounted successfully, but /sbin/init does not exist.` I did it as root)

**SOLVE:**
In `Arch`

```
ln -s ../lib/systemd/systemd /sbin/init
```

(Thank  terdon
♦)

Comment: What happened when you tried this with Arch? What errors did you get? Also, what user ran the `ln` command? Did you confirm that after the `ln` you had a `/sbin/init -> ../lib/systemd/systemd` symlink? What permissions did the link have? Does it work if you try this instead: `sudo ln -s ../lib/systemd/systemd /sbin/init`?

Comment: After removing /sbin/init in `Arch`, it showed `ERROR: Root device mounted successfully, but /sbin/init does not exist.` .I did this as root user.

Comment: OK. Please [edit] your question and include that (we always need to know the exact errors). Then also show us the output of `ls -l /sbin/init` so we can see if there is such a file, if it is a symlink, and what it is pointing to. Al;so tell us if it works if you try my suggestion instead: `sudo ln -s ../lib/systemd/systemd /sbin/init`

Comment: Oh. Your method works. But how to explain this?

Comment: Please [edit] all this into your question. I can guess the reason, but I don't know enough about how systemd works to be sure. My guess is that it isn't actually mounted under `/lib` when booting, but the files are made accessible in some other way. I know the symlink on my Arch is pointing to `../lib/systemd/systemd` which suggests they had a good reason to use relative paths. However, someone else will need to explain exactly why one system works this way and the other does not, but they will need to see this info in the question.

Comment: Welcome to the site. Please don't edit your question to contain the answer - write [your own answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/self-answer) instead.

Comment: Have you removed the *symlink* `/lib`?

Comment: Absolutely not ...

Comment: @terdon
♦   I have tried doing something to figure out it :

In `Arch`, I tried to let Linux kernel directly invoke `bash` through boot process. So I made `/sbin/init` to symbol link to `../bin/bash`, as I expected, which invoked successfully but not if `/sbin/init` sym-link to `/bin/bash`.

By contrast, on `Ubuntu`, it will invoke bash happily in these two ways.

It seems that this problem has nothing to do with `systemd` or any other userspace programs but Linux kernel configuration.

Comment: It will be related to how the directories are mounted during boot. On Ubuntu, it looks like `/lib` is available while on Arch it looks like it isn't so a link pointing to `/lib/...` will be broken.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out:

```
$ ls -l /tmp/sbin
lrwxrwxrwx 1 tom tom 7 Jul 29 23:32 /tmp/sbin -> usr/bin
$ ls -l /tmp/lib
ls: cannot access '/tmp/lib': No such file or directory
$ ls -l /tmp/usr/
total 0
drwxr-xr-x 2 tom tom 80 Jul 29 23:34 bin
drwxr-xr-x 3 tom tom 60 Jul 29 23:34 lib
$ ls -l /tmp/usr/bin/
total 0
lrwxrwxrwx 1 tom tom 20 Jul 29 23:33 inita -> /lib/systemd/systemd
lrwxrwxrwx 1 tom tom 22 Jul 29 23:33 initb -> ../lib/systemd/systemd
$ ls -l /tmp/usr/lib/
total 0
drwxr-xr-x 2 tom tom 60 Jul 29 23:34 systemd
$ ls -l /tmp/usr/lib/systemd/
total 0
-rwxr-xr-x 1 tom tom 0 Jul 29 23:34 systemd
$ realpath /tmp/sbin/init{a,b}
/usr/lib/systemd/systemd
/tmp/usr/lib/systemd/systemd
```

And then take a look at these lines of the "early" init (script) that used by default in Arch:

https://github.com/archlinux/mkinitcpio/blob/v30/init#L5

https://github.com/archlinux/mkinitcpio/blob/v30/init#L57

Consider `/tmp` in the above to be `/new_root`. You should then see why it's wrong to use `init(a) -> /lib/systemd/systemd`:

> `/` (root) refers to a totally different thing before and after it switches root.

Before it's just a ramfs (or maybe actually, tmpfs?) where the content of the initramfs / initcpio are extracted to. After it's the filesystem that is used for the "real root" (i.e. what is mounted on `/new_root`).

Since the check is done before it switches root:

https://github.com/archlinux/mkinitcpio/blob/v30/init#L76

It will not find `/usr/lib/systemd/systemd`.

I don't know what exactly is used as the early init in Ubuntu. There's a chance that it is systemd (mkinitcpio allows you to do so in Arch as well. You just need to include the systemd hook.) Probably systemd will not use `/sbin/init` or `/usr/bin/init` to locate its copy in the real root, but rather simply `/lib/systemd/systemd` or `/usr/lib/systemd/systemd`.

P.S. Since when you use the systemd hook, a copy of `usr/lib/systemd/systemd` (in the real root) will be added to the initramfs / initcpio. If it also includes (which I didn't bother to check) a `lib -> usr/lib` symlink, `sbin/init` (`usr/bin/init`) will ultimately lead to the `usr/lib/systemd/systemd` (in the aforementioned ramfs / tmpfs) even if it points to `/lib/systemd/systemd`. (There's a reason that I removed all leading `/` in all paths but `/lib/systemd/systemd`. See if you can understand why.)

P.S. You might wonder why `realpath /tmp/sbin/inita` in my test returned `/usr/lib/systemd/systemd` even when I didn't have a `/tmp/lib` pointing to `usr/lib`. The reason is `/tmp/sbin/inita` is resolved into `/tmp/usr/bin/inita` which points to `/lib/systemd/systemd` which is resolved to `/usr/lib/systemd/systemd`.

Comment: The links are very helpful since I didn't know these details of Arch boot. Thanks.